# Specifying the width and height of a webview in android

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to copy a webview's texture into a 500x500 pixel OpenGL texture using a bitmap and canvas (which are both 500x500 as well). I call the `draw(Canvas canvas)` method on the webview, but it doesn't fit properly into the 500x500 texture because the webview seems to be the dimensions of the device's screen. Is there a way to set the dimensions of the webview, ideally in pixels, so it fits properly into the texture?

I attempted to set `setUseWideViewPort` to `true` and adjusted the width and height in the meta tag in HTML, which had some effect on the dimensions. Setting the width and height to a large value (6000) seemed to fit more content into the texture, but I don't know how to perfectly fit the webview into it. Thanks for any help!